# Generate report from mysql, errors appear

Tags: php, mysql, dompdf

heres my code , when i first try to display all the data from my database using my query it appears, but when i add this to my query WHERE SECTION = '$.thissection'" i got pdf error , and it doest work even i have  set the POST to call the value on my page, what is wrong of my codes , please i really need it,

```
    include_once( 'dompdf\dompdf_config.inc.php');

    $html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="container">
         <caption><h2 style="margin-left: 180px;">St. Therese Lisioux School of Cainta </h2></caption>
          <table class="zebra">







     $thissubject = $_POST['subject'];
    $thissection = $_POST['section'];
    $thisgrade_level = $_POST['grade_level']; 

      $sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT si.STUDENT_ID, concat(si.LNAME,',  ',si.FNAME) as Name,
                  sg.*
                  From student_info si Left join grades sg On si.STUDENT_ID = sg.STUDENT_NO 
                  WHERE SECTION = '$.thissection'"); 
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery))
        {

        $student_id = $row['STUDENT_NO'];
        $Name  = $row['Name'];
        $SUBJECT_NAME = $row['SUBJECT'];
        $first_Grading = $row['FIRST_GRADING'];
        $second_Grading = $row['SECOND_GRADING'];
        $third_Grading =   $row['THIRD_GRADING'];
        $fourth_Grading =$row['FOURTH_GRADING'];
        $final = $row['FINAL'];
        $status = $row['STATUS'];


       $html .= '<tbody>
        <tr class="warning">
          <td>'.$student_id.'</td>
          <td>'.$Name.'</td>
          <td>'.$SUBJECT_NAME.'</td>
          <td>'.$first_Grading.'</td>
          <td>'.$second_Grading.'</td>
          <td>'.$third_Grading.'</td>
          <td>'.$fourth_Grading.'</td>
          <td>'.$final.'</td>
          <td>'.$status.'</td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>';



        }

  $html .= ' </table>
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    ';

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf ->set_paper("a4", "landscape");
    $dompdf ->load_html($html);
    $dompdf ->render();
    $dompdf ->stream('Student_report.pdf');

  ?>strong text
```

Comment: Severe PHP Syntax error! Use slash instead of backslash in `include_once()` and you use PHP codes within a variable?

Comment: Please format your code properly!

Answer (score 1):

Your codes have severe PHP syntax errors.

1. You use PHP codes within a single-quoted string variable, which is not parsed by PHP parser.
2. Also, you didn't escape the the codes.
3. Use slash instead of backslash in `include_once()`
4. You didn't initialize your MySQL connection
5. stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions and your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow POST values to be inserted in your query. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.
6. Your HTML lacks `<title>`
7. Where is your error handling mechanism? You expect no errors for all sorts of inputs?

For a quick fix, change the line:

```
<table class="zebra">
```

to

```
<table class="zebra">';
```

in order to end the `$html` variable.